# sketch the region of integration for $\int_0^2 \int_0^x \int_0^y f(x,y,z) \,dz\,dy\,dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^x \int_0^y f(x,y,z) \,dz\,dy\,dx$$

From what I can understand that the region should be between planes $x=0$, $x=2$ and $y=0$, $y=x$ and $z=0$, $z=y$.

I am finding it very difficult to represent it on a piece of paper. Please advise.

Comment: If you at least have an idea, I recommend drawing it out and checking that the integration boundaries make sense for your surface. Wrong or right, I've found this helps to gain some geometric intuition for the problem (and if wrong, hopefully suggests a correction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right the limit to consider are

- $0\le x \le 2$ varing along $x$ axis
- $0\le y \le x$ varing in $x-y$ plane between $x$ axis and the line $y=x$
- $0\le z \le y$ varing in space between $x-y$ plane and the plane $z=y$

A good way to vizualize without a 3D plot program is try to make at first some sketch in the $x-y$, $y-z$, $x-z$ planes and then try to vizualize the region in 3D.

Here below an example

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the integration region:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! but I am solving a question from the book and I have to answer it on a paper. I don't know how to represent it on a paper.

Comment: Sketch my figure with pen and paper.  Mark the corner points and simply draw straight lines between them.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing cross-sections may be beneficial.

$x=0, x=2$ and $y=0, y=x$ define a right triangular prism, infinite in the $z$-direction. Draw its cross-section in the $z=c$ plane (I'd probably consider $c=0$ here for the $xy$-plane).

Now consider the intersections with $z=0$, if you haven't done so, and $z=y$. The former gives a right triangular base, and the latter cuts through your prism at a $\pi/4$ angle.

You could consider drawing the cross-section from another perspective as well - say choosing three projections flattening one of the cartesian components.